# Get count value from a nested sql-query with Liferay Dynamic Query

Tags: liferay, dynamicquery

Could anybody clarify to me if is it possible accomplishing the following sql statement (MVC example) from within the Dynamic Query world:

```
select count(*) from <sub_select> where aggregate_field >= J;

<sub_select>::
(select case
when condition1 then 1
when condition2 then 2
...
when conditionN then N
else 0
end as aggregate_field
from Entity) as select1

J={1..N}  // J can range 1 to N
```

The thing is I have to calculate the number of rows satisfiying the where-condition `aggregate_field >= J`, but the field `aggregate_field` doesn't belong to the table `Entity`, but it's calculated depending on some conditions.

There's no problem to create a DynamicQuery object to execute the sub_select:

```
subQuery = EntityLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();
subQuery.setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.sqlProjection("case when ... end as aggregate_field", new String[] { "aggregate_field" }, new Type[] { Type.INTEGER });
EntityLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(subQuery);
```

But I don't know how to do to create a `DynamiQuery` object to get the number of rows of the table linked to subQuery satisfiying the where-condition.

Any ideas about how to accomplish the intended task will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it's better to write a custom sql query. DynamicQuery maybe it's not the right way.

Look at https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018179071-Developing-Custom-SQL-Queries

Comment: the thing is I don't manage any `service.xml` file, so I don't think I could face that task from a Custom SQL perspective. In fact, I'm implementing an override class that overrides a Liferay kernel's service wrapper class, and the `Entity` involved is Liferay's`ddmcontent` table.

Comment: BTW, is it possible tu use Custom Query w/o defining (and managing) a `service.xml` file?

Comment: You can create a ServiceBuilder "Entity" without any fields - which doesn't create a table, but gives you access to all of the SB infrastructure, e.g. finders and the CustomSql options. I'd recommend to use this, rather than figuring out how to get a raw database connection.

Comment: @OlafKock the solution you propose sounds brilliant, and I'll take it into consideration. However, I've just posted a solution I came to on my own. I'd really appreciate if you could clarify to me if it's a good practice or not within the Liferay's world.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share how I've managed to get a raw database connection. My solution is based on the use of the class `DLFolderUtil`, which is a persistence utility that wraps the `-Impl` class `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.persistence.impl.DLFolderPersistenceImpl`, which provides direct access to the database for CRUD operations. Then, the way to get acess to the `openSession()` method is as described next:

```
Session session = DLFolderUtil.getPersistence().openSession();
```

And then, you can work the way you do with an Hibernate session:

```
String sql = "select ... "; // whatever complex query you can think of
SQLQuery q = session.createSynchronizedSQLQuery(sql);
List<?> list = q.list();
```

I don't know if what I've done is a good practice or not to do when working with the original Liferay database, but it's a kind of a quite easy solution.

Comment: Not good practice. Make extra extra _extra_ sure that you return all the resources that you borrow this way, otherwise you'll run into issues later, e.g. when the connection pool is exhausted, or when other memory leaks.

Comment: @OlafKock I was only thinking on closing the `session` once the `list` object has been filled up. I'm just mimic-ing the way the DLApp portlet works.